# Qt method for evaluating Flash scripts

Tags: flash, qt, google-maps

Like Qt has `evaluateJavascript` function for the working with the `Javascript`, is there something similar for `Flash` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is worth mentioning here that the `Qtitan` namespace of `QtitanMultimedia` class, and `QGraphicsView` class together are responsible for displaying SWF files in Qt:
http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/4827

The free trial download link of the component `QtitanMultimedia`: http://www.devmachines.com/downloads/free-demo-version.html

Comment: Might it be better to include this in your original question? Or does it provide an answer?

Comment: @Bart Yes, that is an answer since the code for doing the same has also been shown in the nested link. You still think I should delete this answer and put it in the question?